# i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph"

Tags: dart

Dart just stopped compiling and started throwing this error. Any idea what causes this?

```
i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph" (data:text/html,chromewebdata:3183)
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

Comment: What kind of application do you have? Did you launch it from DartEditor? Did you restart DartEditor and try again?

Comment: I am trying to make game using stagexl framework http://www.stagexl.org/. And after restarting same proble. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
  http://localhost:8080/index.html
i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph" (data:text/html,chromewebdata:3183)
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Try deleting the `. pub` directory in your project directory  and run `pub cache repair` from command line.

Comment: is .pub directory is the package folder created with the project?

Comment: I couldn't find any .pub directory in my project so I ran pub cache repair directly and still the same issue

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Maybe reinstall Dart. Some mentioned this solved some problems for them but was never necessary for me. What Dart version are you using.

Comment: Dart Editor Version 1.9.1 and Dart SDK 1.9.1

Comment: That's not the Dart compielr giving that error. That looks to me like something on the page is trying to get data from a data URL in order to fill in something for internationalization. But i18n-values is not part of Dart or of StageXL, so I'd guess you have some other component on the page that's complaining.